# ASP.NET Core ActionFilter Dependency Injection ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I want to create a global action filter to audit all requests to my API. I want to use a globally registered `ActionFilter` to ensure all API Controller Actions are audited. I want to inject a scoped instance of `AuditService`, however, I get a `System.ObjectDisposedException` when calling `_auditService.Create`. What is the correct way to inject a scoped service into an `ActionFilter` so that it doesn't get disposed of before `OnActionExecuted` is called? The service is also disposed of before the `OnActionExecuting` event.

Startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ..
    services.AddControllers(c => c.Filters.Add<AuditFilter>());
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString"));
    services.AddScoped<IAuditService, AuditService>();
    // ..
}
```

Action Filter:

```
public class AuditFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IAuditService _auditService;

    public AuditFilter(IAuditService auditService)
    {
        _auditService = auditService;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        
    }

    public async void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string username = ClaimsPrincipal.Current?.Identity?.Name;
        string remoteAddr = $"{context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}:{context.HttpContext.Connection.RemotePort}";
        string queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value : null;
        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        body = body.Length > 0 ? body : null;
        // System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance
        await _auditService.Create(username, remoteAddr, context.HttpContext.Request.Method,
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path, queryString, body, DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Audit Service:

```
public class AuditService : IAuditService
{
    private DRSContext Context { get; }

    public AuditService(DRSContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Create(string username, string remoteAddr, string httpMethod, string path, string query,
        string body, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        await Context.AuditLogs.AddAsync(new AuditLog
        {
            Username = username,
            RemoteAddress = remoteAddr,
            HttpMethod = httpMethod,
            Path = path,
            Query = query,
            Body = body,
            Timestamp = timestamp
        });
        return await Context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
    }

    // ..
}
```

Comment: Most likely the injected `IAuditService` implementation is using the scoped `DbContext` when it gets disposed after the request. Use the `HttpContext.RequestServices` to create a local scope and perform your function. And there is also the `async void` being used.

Comment: firstly you should use `IResourceFilter` to ensure that all resource accesses are audited (page handlers will ***not*** invoke `IActionFilter`). Secondly I think this may not show the whole picture, the problem could be somewhere else, or something wrong inside the implementation of your `IAuditService`. Generally speaking, this could be caused by wrong caching, wrong way of running background tasks, explicitly disposing the DbContext ... you need to scan through all your project to find it.

Comment: @KingKing I have added my `AuditService` class to question. I will look into `IResourceFilter`.

Comment: your `Dispose` implementation may be the issue here, somehow that's called before the `DbContext` is being used again. You don't need to explicitly dispose the `DbContext` like that. Because it will be managed by the DI container. And `Dispose` is usually for unmanaged resources.

Comment: @mr.coffee review docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#implementation Your async void is a fire and forget invocation so the DbContext is going out of scope before your filter completes its function. Review your design choice.

Comment: if you want to use `async`, use `IAsyncActionFilter` instead (and better as I said earlier, use `IAsyncResourceFilter`).

Comment: @KingKing Changing to `IAsyncActionFilter ` stopped the exception. Additionally I removed explicit dispose so the DI container can manage that. I will look into using `IAsyncResourceFilter`

Comment: @KingKing Post your comment as an answer and I will mark as accepted.

Comment: OK, I've summarized all the ideas commented here (as pointed out by @Nkosi as well) in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things wrong in your code here:

- You use `async void` on the `OnActionExecuted`. This should be avoided because of unpredictable results you may have. If you want to use `async` code, try implementing `IAsyncActionFilter` instead.
- You implement `Dispose` for your implementation class of `IAuditService` in which you explicitly dispose the `DbContext`. You don't need to do that manually which can go out-of-sync with how the DI manages the `DbContext` (as scoped service) for you. Usually code inside `Dispose` is used to dispose unmanaged resources.

Finally I would suggest you to use `IAsyncResourceFilter` instead. It will be invoked by both controller actions & page handlers whereas the `IAsyncActionFilter` will be executed only by controller actions. You can examine the `ResourceExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor` to know about the action. It can be a `ControllerActionDescriptor` or a `PageActionDescriptor`.